# Binding two lists to one datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am currently trying to bind two lists to a datagrid in wpf

```
   int rows = Convert.ToInt32(rowsTB.Text);
        double offset = Convert.ToDouble(offsetTB.Text);
        double startValue = Convert.ToDouble(startValueTB.Text);
        List<double> valuesList = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            valuesList.Add(startValue += offset);
        }

        List<double> maxList = new List<double>();
        foreach (var x in valuesList)
        {
            maxList.Add(MaxValue(x));
        }
        valuesGrid.ItemsSource = valuesList;
        maxGrid.ItemsSource = maxList;
```

This is my current snippet for what I currently have, I have created two datagrids each with one column and each datagrid is binded to a list, but this is not what I really want, I want to have 1 datagrid with 2 columns each binded to a list.

And if there is a possibility to do it with a one ojbect that has 2 lists can you please provide me with an example? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either construct a `DataTable` or create a custom object and add it to a single `List`. I'd prefer a custom object since it is more OOP-like. So to construct a custom object, create this class...

```
public class DataItem
{
    public double Values {get; set;}
    public double MaxValue {get; set;}
}
```

Then do all the processing you were doing but instead add the `DataItem` class to the list...

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
{
    DataItem item = new DataItem();
    item.Value = startValue += offset;
    item.MaxValue = MaxValue(item.Value);

    valuesList.Add(item);
}
```

And finally, bind tbe list to the `DataGrid`...

```
valuesGrid.ItemsSource = valuesList;
```

Comment: Thank you! one this is that the values in the datagrid are not being binded correctly, or maybe I need casting or something because now each cell is filled with something like "wpfapplication.mainwindow.dataitem"

Comment: Well, of course, you need to set the binding expressions in the columns...I was assuming you knew all that stuff...it'll look like something similar to this...`<dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" />`

Comment: My fault!, i set the binding but without a path :D Thanks a lot! really appreciate it :)